# Spring NamedParameterJDBCTemplate reuse of Prepared Statements gets slow performance

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

**Requirement:**
Have to insert a row to database table multiple times (may be like 50,000 times in a batch job)
Database used: MS SQL Server

**Approach taken:**
Used `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and `PreparedStatement` to implement the above.
For example,

```
String query = "insert into table_Name (Column1, Column2, column3) values (?,?,?)";
```

Then by the help of `PreparedStatement`, I have assigned dynamic values to the `?` fields in the insert query and then triggered `executeUpdate` function of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to execute the insert query.

This above process is repeated multiple times; every time creating new insert queries with different values in the fields `?` by the help of `PreparedStatement`.

**Issue:**
Performance of the `executeUpdate` function of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is very slow.

**After few research, I got the below explanation:**

"The cost based optimizer (that 's what we 're talking about, not) makes its
choices based on the availability of indexes (among other objects), and the
distribution of values in the indexes (how selective the index will be for a
given value). Obviuosly, when working with bind variables, the suitability
of the index from a distribution point of view is harder to determine. The
optimizer has no way to determine beforehand to what value matches will be
sought. This might (should) lead to another execution plan. No surprise
here, as far as I am concerned."

https://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/65559-jdbc-oracle-beware-bind-variables

A `PreparedStatement` has two advantages over a regular Statement:

- We add parameters to the SQL using methods instead of doing it inside the SQL query itself. With this we avoid SQL injection attacks and also let the driver to do type conversions for us.
- The same `PreparedStatement` can be called with different parameters, and the database engine can reuse the query execution plan.

It seems that `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` helps us with the first advantage, but does nothing for the latter.

**Query:**

If `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` does not helps us with the second advantage, then what is the alternative solution instead of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

Comment: Why are you even using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` if you aren't using named parameters? Use a regular `JdbcTemplate` instead. Also indexes are for selecting (and are updated after insert/update statements) when doing inserts it has nothing to do with indexes. Also what is slow per query or overall or? What have you measured? How are you using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` (I would suggest a plain `JdbcTemplate` as you aren't using named parameters).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum 
Using JdbcTemplate solved the issue. It became much more faster.